# Swift: hex number to Decimal from signed 2's complement Uint8

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an array UInt8, I want to convert a hex number to decimal 2's complement:

```
var command = [UInt8]()
        command.append(0x24)
        command.append(0x17)
        command.append(UInt8(101))
        command.appendWithUint32Lsb(0)
        command.append(200)
        command.append(0)
        command.append(0xC8)
        command.append(0)
        command.append(0x20)
        command.append(3)
        command.append(7)
        command.append(0x00)
        command.append(UInt8(colors.count / 3))
        command.append(0xC8) <---- IR
```

According to this site https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html?x=0xC8

0xc8:
Decimal number = 200

Decimal from signed 2's complement = -56

In my code when I print it:

```
[36, 23, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 200, 0, 32, 3, 7, 0, 3, 200]
```

But I do not want it to be 200 but -56

Here is the result I want:

```
[36, 23, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 200, 0, 32, 3, 7, 0, 3, -56]
```

How to do this?

Comment: That's indeed strange, but since it's the same, the fact that it's signed/unsigned is an interpretation of the bits, so it should be okay in the end.

Comment: For the bluetooth device I work he prefers the negative number

Comment: What is UInt16lsb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is currently of type `[UInt8]` - it can't hold a value of `-56`.

Try this instead:

```
var command = [Int8]()
command.append(Int8(bitPattern: 0x24))
...
command.append(Int8(bitPattern: 0xc8))
```

Or transform what you already have:

```
let signedCommand = command.map { Int8(bitPattern: $0) }
```